# Template Class with function pointer doesn't accept specialisation

Tags: c++, templates

I am trying to create a template so that I can have a function pointer (for a callback function) that accepts both a Class as a base for member functions as well as as having a way to have globally defined functions.

At the moment I have

```
template <class c>
struct Callback {
    typedef void(c::*callback)(void);
};
```

Which works and will allow me to use Callback::callback as a type

However when I try and add a specific implementation such as:

```
class VOIDCLASS {
    void * void_ptr;
};
// Callback template declaration as above here
template <VOIDCLASS>
struct Callback {
    typedef void(*callback)(void);
};
```

I get a compiler error : error C3855: 'Callback': template parameter 'c' is incompatible with the declaration
This is using Visual Studio 2013 with a platform tool-set of v110(VS2012) and Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An explicit specialization is written like this:

```
template<>
struct Callback<VOIDCLASS> {
    typedef void(*callback)(void);
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you meant:

```
template <>
struct Callback<VOIDCLASS>
{
    typedef void(*callback)(void);
};
```